# Docker laravel invalid host header

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

When i run
`docker-compose build` 
i got error
http: invalid Host header

```
Docker version 
 docker --version   
Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128
```

I got this error on all my docker projects.

I only encountered this problem on Ubuntu. The same project can be assembled on Windows without any problems. I tried to rebuild different projects. Everywhere the same error.
These are Lаravel projects. Previously a build without problems.

Comment: Ensure your `docker-compose` version is compatible with your Docker version. Check the version with: `docker-compose --version`